# Estimate numerical error in eigenvalues computation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, approximation, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a large sparse symmetric matrix (say of dimension $N\geq 10^6$). I compute its largest eigenvalues using the power method. Suppose I got approximate eigenvalue $\lambda'$ with eigenvector $v'$ at some step of the computation.

Question: If $|Av'-\lambda'v'|\leq 10^{-k}$, can one estimate how close is $\lambda'$ to the actual eigenvalue?

Comment: Just a pointer this may be related to the theory of pseudo spectra http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Pseudospectrum . Which characterize the set of eigenvalues of a matrix under small perturbation.. (But this does not cover the numerical inprecision part.